# qpython3 printing variable after string

Tags: qpython3

I'm wanting to print a variable after a string but the variable doesn't show.
I'm following a book called learning python the hard way.
In it, it asks to declare a variable:

```py
cars = 100

Print ("how many cars are there"), (cars)
```

And print it after a string.

However, it only prints the string. I've tried doing it in different ways with brackets, parentheses, etc. to no avail. Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

```py
cars = 100

print ("text", (cars) ,"text")
```

Thanks anyways